# How to create OR logic filters across multiple columns using ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, vue.js, ag-grid

ag-grid only promotes the use of filtering columns based on `AND`,and they allow you to do`AND/OR` within a single column itself, but so far I have not been able to find the ability to do a filter using `OR` across multiple columns.

For instance, if I wanted a filter group for (`Status1 = 5` OR `Status1 = 6`) OR (`Age > 30`).

The first group would currently work, Status1 equals 5 or 6, but doing an OR for age is the question, how could this be accomplished? If it's even possible at all without a ton of additional custom configuration?

Documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/

Example of the filtering: 
https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php#/filtering/1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using custom filters you can do the following. I am using another column 'Active' as an example.

- When defining another column add a colId:"Active"; //Active is just some unique string
- In your doesFilterPass implementation you can process the incoming parameters with other column filter.

```
  doesFilterPass(params: IDoesFilterPassParams): boolean {
        const passesHere ... your filter logic
        // Get the other filter.
        const activeFilterPasses = this.api.getFilterInstance('Active').doesFilterPass(params);
        return passesHere && activeFilterPasses; // Here it does AND filter between two columns. 
    }
```